# Assigning unique item permissions to an item(When a new item is created) - office 365 sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, office-365

A client is using office 365 sharepoint online.I would like assign item permissions (from a field in the list that would list users or groups) automatically to an item.
I reckon this can only be achieve via workflow.
Can i use sharepoint designer 2013 workflow to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can achieve this using designer Workflow since SharePoint 2013 designer also supports creation of SP 2010 workflows. Create a Workflow with SharePoint 2010 workflow platform(Since 2013 workflows does not have impersonation step). In the workflow add an impersonation step. Inside impersonation step add **Replace List item permissions** action. Give the necessary permissions to the user/group in the particular field.
Start the workflow in item Added event.

See this [blog](http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html) for more details.

Comment: So this is no longer possible in 365, or do you just need to use the old workflow platform?

Comment: In SP 2013 designer you can create 2010 workflow also. So this is very much possible